# using dropzone.js or normal js to handle csv in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, file, dropzone

I am using dropzone.js to handle csv imports. Here is my code for the dropzone:

```
<form onsubmit="csvImport()" class="dropzone" id="mydrop"></form>
```

Currently csvImport method uses a hardcoded csv file like this:

```
function csvImport() {

            $(document).ready(function() {
                //fetch file
                $.get('/directory/test.csv', function(data) {
                 //do something here
                }
    
             }
 }
```

How can I integrate the dropzone functionality to use the given csv file instead of hardcoding the path below? I do not need to use dropzone.js I can use another library or plain JS.

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an event listener on the Dropzone instance, as they describe here https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

Here's their example.

```
// The recommended way from within the init configuration:
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
  }
};
```

You can then store it somewhere, such as in a global variable, and then operate on or validate it in your onSubmit handler if you wish.